# Jenkins: trigger only on selected SVN Revisions

Tags: jenkins, svn, tortoisesvn

We try to setup **Jenkins** with **SVN** repository (**TortoiseSVN**). We are new to Jenkins while we use SVN extensively.

Our code is continuously committed to SVN. There is no need to trigger Jenkins on every revision.

Is it possible to **trigger Jenkins only if SVN revision is specially marked** for triggering? For example, can Jenkins be triggered only if revision is tagged?

Comment: This needs more information. Like are you using post commit hook to trigger the build jobs or something else. In case you are using post-commit hook it is better to use the post-commit script to trigger jobs on specific commit or commit message.

Comment: Siddharth Kaul, thank you for the answer. I am completely new to Jenkins.

I was thinking to trigger Jenkins by timer every evening. But triggering should not mean starting build immediately. Could Jenkins control SVN repository for new tags then download and build last tagged version?

Comment: It is easier to do the reverse. Once the tag is created your post commit script would trigger the jenkins build job. Post commit scripts give you flexibility to do things your way. It should also be possible to do this in jenkins as well. But post commit script is the most common and easier way